# Launch Screen Mirroring from Ionic or Flutter app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, flutter

I have a Samsung S5e tablet with scrren mirroring capabilities, named Smart View on this device. I need to make an app to launch this functionality inside it, but it seems that it's a non-ui app (a server app) and I cant launch it like other apps.

Does anyone knows a way or can give me a clue to perform this task?

I have tried the device_apps flutter package but only find installed apps with ui.